# Can't edit input when assigning a value with useReducer hook

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to handle multiple inputs using React's `useReducer` and everything is ok. But when I try to set a value for the input, I can't edit its value.

I'm using React v16.8.6

```
// input tag
<input type="text" name="strWork" value={stateUserInput.strWork} onChange={handleInputChange} />;

// use useReducer to handle Multiple Inputs
const [stateUserInput, dispatchSetUserInput] = useReducer((state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }), {
  strWork: '',
});

function handleInputChange(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  const name = target.name;

  dispatchSetUserInput({ [name]: value });
}

// try to set value on input in useEffect Hook, but then I can't edit it
useEffect(() => {
  dispatchSetUserInput({
    strWork: 'Hello world',
  });
});
```

I expect I can edit the value of the input, but I can't, and there is no error on console tab.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the way to fix problem that we can't edit input when assigning value: **add dependency for useEffect. It work!!!**

we have isSelected is a prop with value 'Hello world'

```
  useEffect(() => {
  dispatchSetUserInput({
    strWork: isSelected,
  });
},[isSelected])
```

Another way: found a way to fix this using useState Hook (also for multiple inputs):

We have 2 inputs:

```
<input className="form-control mr-1" type="text" name="strWork" placeholder="Nhập công việc..." value={inputForm.strWork} onChange={handleChangeInputForm} />
<select name="strLevel" value={inputForm.strLevel} onChange={handleChangeInputForm}>
    <option value={0}>Low</option>
    <option value={1}>Normal</option>
    <option value={2}>High</option>
 </select>
```

Use React's useState to handle multiple inputs:

```
const [inputForm, setInputForm] = useState({
        strWork: '',
        strLevel: 2
    })
const handleChangeInputForm = (event) => {
        const target = event.target
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value
        const name = target.name
        setInputForm(prev => ({ 
            ...prev,
            [name]: value
        }))
    }
```

Set value on it (and you still can edit it):

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (isSelected !== null) {
            setInputForm(prev => ({ 
                ...prev,
                strWork: isSelected.name,
                strLevel: isSelected.level
            }))
        }
    },[isSelected])
```